# Drools : How to write a rule that hits when data is not available in entry point

Tags: java, spring-boot, streaming, drools, entry-point

I am new to drools. I am expecting a sensor data that will send data from a tracking device (like a tag device). I am using Drools **entry point** to track the sensor data. I need to do some alerts on some events based on this sensor data.

**DRL file is as below**

```
import com.sample.AlertRuleModel;

declare AlertRuleModel 
    @role( event )
    @timestamp( timespamp )
end

rule "No signals are coming from any entry-point for more than 10s"
     when
        $f : AlertRuleModel() from entry-point "AlertRuleStream"
        not(AlertRuleModel(this != $f, this after[0s, 10s] $f) from entry-point "AlertRuleStream")
    then
        $f.setRuleId(1);
        <Do alert here>
end

rule "Rule on Tag1 has not been in zone1 for more than 1 minutes"
     when
         $f : AlertRuleModel( tagId == 1, zoneId == 1 ) from entry-point "AlertRuleStream"
         not(AlertRuleModel(this != $f, tagId == 1, zoneId != 1, this after[0s, 1m] $f) from entry-point "AlertRuleStream")
    then
         $f.setRuleId(2);
        <Do alert here>
end
```

**Java code**

```
    kSession = RuleExecutionService.getKieSession(packetProcessorData.getAlertRuleDrlPath());
    ruleStream = kSession.getEntryPoint("AlertRuleStream");
    kSession.addEventListener(new DefaultAgendaEventListener() {
        public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event) {
            super.afterMatchFired(event);
            onPostExecution(event, RuleTypeEnum.ALERT_RULE.getName());
        }
    });
    
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            kSession.fireUntilHalt();
        }
    }.start();
```

*Stream data insertion part*

```
private BlockingQueue<AlertRuleModel> alertFactQueue;
.
.
AlertRuleModel alertRuleModel = null;
while (true) {
    alertRuleModel = alertFactQueue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (alertRuleModel != null) {
        //LOGGER.debug("Inserting alertRuleModel into \"AlertRuleStream\"");
        ruleStream.insert(alertRuleModel);
        continue;
    } 

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while sleeping thread during alertFactQueue polling..", e);
    }

}
```

But when i run application,

1. First rule "No signals are coming from any entry-point for more than 10s" is not hitting at all. I dont know why, please tell me if i am doing anything wrong or any syntax error is for first rule.
2. In case of second rule "Tag1 has not been in zone1 for more than 1 minutes", it alway hit immediately when i pass fact with tagId == 1 and zoneId == 1. I tried with different time gaps like **after[0s, 10m]**. But still it hits immediately after passing fact with above values.

Please tell me where i am making mistakes..?

Comment: your rule expects at least one event in knowledge base to start track time from. Did you inserted first event and then wait 10 seconds or you just wait 10 seconds?

Comment: Hi @Mike i tired both. As i mentioned above "when i pass fact with tagId == 1 and zoneId == 1" it immediately hits on rule2. Then i waited for too long without passing any events to engine. But still rule1 is not hitting which i exected onmevent "No signals are coming from any entry-point for more than 10s"...

Comment: I tested your code without @timestamp field, it works as expected, it behaves exactly how it is implied. Could you try the same, maybe you have issues with initializing timestamp value? If you omit the value it will rely on drools inner clock, otherwise on your provided value, maybe it is wrong (timezone etc.).